# How can I create a CSS selector to select when a link does not have a class of folder or start class starting with title?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a CSS selector to select links that do not have a class starting with title and do not have a class of folder. These are the closest I have got but they still give me a syntax error in VS2012. Can anyone suggest how I can fix this?

```
ul.arbo li > a:not(a[class^='title']),a:not(".folder"):hover span,

ul.arbo li > a:not([class*="title-"], [class="folder"]):hover span,
```

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/KwmUN/ ?

Comment: @Passerby: you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, extending from comment:

Try

```css
a:not([class^="title"]):not(.folder)
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KwmUN/)

**Edit**:

Following @PavloMykhalov 's suggestion, in case you need "class name start with 'title'" not "class attribute start with 'title'", added one more selector:

```
a:not([class^="title"]):not([class*=" title"]):not(.folder)
```

[Updated jsfiddle deom](http://jsfiddle.net/KwmUN/1/)

Comment: I suggest to add `:not([class*=" title"])` in case `title*` is not the first class in a list.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov OP indicates that he need to filter out "a class starting with title".

Comment: "A class starting with a title", not an html attribute `class` starting with a "title". `<a class="wtf title"></a>` will have 2 classes, the second is starting with a "title". That is my suggestion for.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov I'm not sure if OP is that precise in language. Better let him clarify. Anyway, I added your suggestion to my answer.